# For persons aged 25 and over in the US would the average or the median be higher for income?

Tags: inference, median, mean, central-tendency

Question:

```
For persons aged 25 and over in the US would the average
or the median be higher for income?
```

---

I'm not sure how to answer this.

If I assume that the wage increases with age, and that every age range is
equally represented, then perhaps I'll (extremely roughly) have a graph like
this :

[image]

There the y axis is the wage,and the x axis is representing age.

Then the median wage is where half people earn more, and half of the people earn
less. And the mean wage is the average wage that people will earn.

In this case the mean will be greater than the median.

But I'm not sure if this is an appropriate way to consider this problem, or how
to explain it clearly.

Comment: Hint: draw a histogram of what you think a random sample of these incomes would look like.

Comment: If age were uniformly distributed between 25 & 75, & income were an exact linear function of age, what distribution would income have? An asymmetric one?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow , and I don't know what age ranges I'm meant to be doing either I just have " over 25 ". So I've presumed that people are working until they're 70 and that their wage increases up until then. Though It wouldn't increase at the same rate etc, I've made it as basic as possible.

Comment: Do you need to assume anything about income as a function of age to answer?

Comment: @Scortchi I think that it would look like a strictly increasing function? And all the information I have is in the original question - edit - so yes it would be asymmetric

Comment: Go back to whuber's hint. Imagine a random sample of over-25-year-olds. You surely have a better idea what the distribution of their incomes would look like than about the relation between their ages & their incomes, & the former is all you're being asked about.

Comment: @Scortchi but if i took a random sample of people over the age of 25, then I can assume that I'll have a selection of people from 25 -> 75 evenly spread... and that the 25 year olds will generally earn less than 30 , and thirty earn less than 40. I think that matching age and earning is a bad choice... someone answered and deleted for some reason

Comment: Hint: Why does age matter at all? Suppose they said "adults" instead of 25+. Would that change your answer? And, again, look at @whuber 's hint.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the average is higher than the median, and the reason is that the distribution of incomes is not symmetric.

In fact, [symmetric distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_probability_distribution) have the same value for the mean and the median. But the income in the US is not symmetric: in fact you have a few people making a lot of money and a lot of people making little money. So that the median is pretty low, compared to the mean: the mean is affected by the rich guys but the median is not.

About your argument, it is probably true that the income is correlated with age but that's not necessarily what makes the distribution asymmetric.